# JSONDecodeError - ValueError exception - getting data

Tags: python, python-3.x

I parse bad json with `json.loads()` in python 3 and get this exception:

```
JSONDecodeError('Expecting value: line 34 column 15 (char 666)',)
```

I want get that 666 as an integer to further handle the problem. Is there a way to do so other than applying regex to extract 666 from the error message?

I am new to python but suspect there should be an underlying object with attributes representing 34, 15, and 666?

Comment: Can you post your JSON data?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONDecodeError

Comment: @JoshLee, that's exactly what i was looking for - solved! and Thanks! feel free to post the answer.